# "Talos Principle" Tetris Puzzle Generator

Tags: code-golf, game

In [Talos Principle](http://croteam.com/talosprinciple/), from time to time player has to solve a puzzle that looks like this:

[image: example]
*Source: http://uk.ign.com/wikis/the-talos-principle/File%3A20141108_134749.jpg*

This puzzle is already solved - the blue slots on the right are the list of the possible blocks the user could use. They were placed in the grid so that they don't overlap and all spaces are filled.

The goal is to create a random puzzle generator that assumes that the grid is 8x8 and lists available puzzles (**16 letters** as output). All blocks from Tetris are allowed (I, L, J, O, T, S and Z) and we assume that the player can rotate them. In the screenshot, the matrix is 4x7 and the program would say that the player has to use two I blocks, two T blocks, two Z blocks and one L block (rotated). The program should generate a puzzle in a reasonable time (let's say a minute on a 1Ghz processor with 8 gigabytes of RAM)

**Winning Criteria** : shortest source code and running within reasonable time, explained above.

Comment: [Related challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47518/tetris-tangrams)

Comment: What are the winning criteria?

Comment: Also, here is another very similar challenge: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30306/solving-a-ubongo-puzzle?rq=1

Comment: @ESultanik: Added winning criteria, does that sound sane? As for the puzzle, mine is about generation.

Comment: Yes, sounds good.

Comment: How random is random? Is it that every possible combo needs to have a non-zero chance? Or is it uniform?

Comment: It doesn't have to be uniform and I'd say that some combos might be excluded.

Comment: It would be useful if, in addition to showing what the puzzle looks like, you explained what the puzzle *is*.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: are you asking because it's actually not clear to you?

Comment: What's the desired output? 16 letters?

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Yes, given that each tetromino takes four blocks and the matrix is 8x8, it should be 16 letters.

Comment: But if all don't have to be possible what's stopping me from doing `print "IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII"`?

Comment: It turns out I'd guessed right, but a good spec shouldn't leave me guessing.

Comment: @Maltysen: nothing, but it's not random. If it's just one possible answer, it's okay.

Comment: Fine but that's not what I meant, what about `random_choose("I"*16, "Other hardcoded puzzle that I cant think of at the moment")`

Comment: @Maltysen: I would say that this is still against this one: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1063/17159